# How to create groups in Excel and make the last group stop at '365 days and more'

Tags: excel

I have 15 employees working on different projects right now. I took all the reception dates of the projects and checked the delay between todays date and the reception dates. it goes from 14 days to about 900 days. I created a pivot table, where I can see every employe and the delays of each projects in a horizontal bar table.

Problem is, the groups are not how I want them to be. i want to be able to see : (0-60 days  - Green color)
 (61-90 days - dark green color)
  (91-150 days - yellow color)
  (151-210 days - orange color)
  (211-365 - red color)
  (365+ - black color)

but this is what I get instead :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Chart Labels**:

As a work-around, since you are working with varying increments, which typically Pivot Tables don't like, you can create a reference table you will vlookup from to pull in the correct labels.

For this reference table, use the lower bound of each bucket you have for the first column `(0, 61, 91, 151, 211, 365)`. The second column should be the labels you want (this will be the 0-60 days).

Next on your raw data add a column and use `=vlookup([lookup], [table], 2, 1)` make sure the lookup is the days you spoke about, and highlight and lock the table you just made, the column reference should be 2 and a non-exact match is what you want. Then pull this into the pivot table and it will give your labels. It's not ideal but will get your result.

**Conditional Format the Table**:

Use the conditional formats. Highlight the value field (where the numbers are) and add conditional formats. Make sure as you add them to hit the `Format` button and select which colors you want. This should achieve what you're looking for. Since it's a table it should re-scale as the table expands.

Home> Conditional Formatting> New Rule > Format only cells that contain

Then `Cell Value` `greater than or equal to` `0`

`Cell Value` `between` `61` and `90`

`Cell Value` `between` `91` and `150`

`Cell Value` `between` `151` and `210`

`Cell Value` `between` `211` and `365`

`Cell Value` `greater than` `365`

Comment: Thanks, will try, but will this automaticly group the days like I asked to? I need to see them visually in the legend...

Comment: Gotcha, let me adjust my answer

Comment: So I added the work-around to give you the bucket labels you want. Pivot tables want even increments, however since yours varies this is the way around that. lmk if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm doing it right now, but how do i name my last group ? we said that the second column should be the labels I want, Can I just name the last one '366+' ? 

I will let you know how everything works out in a minute!

Comment: Yeah I would use "365+ Days", if this is sufficient for answering your question please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I will mark it as answer, i just need to figure things out first since im new to excel. In this formula : '''=vlookup([lookup], [table], 2, 1)'''    [table] stands for what ? The new table I created with the groups? And what does '' 2,1 '' Stand for ? Thanks again

Comment: Yes what i put inside [ ] should be cells on your spreadsheet. The lookup should be the days you spoke about, the table should be the table you just made (make sure the values have the $'s surrounding them, so as you drag down the formula the reference will remain constant.
As for the 2 and the 1, the 2 tells the computer to pull the second column the of the table which is the labels, the 1 means a non-exact reference, so while you have 45 days it will know which bucket it belongs to.

Comment: It's not working.... This is my formula : =VLOOKUP(B2:B196;H1:I7;2,1) It's giving me '' #VALUE!

Comment: do `=vlookup(B2, $H$1:$I$7,2,1)` you had the syntax wrong. I'm assuming the new table is the H1:J7, and you should put this formula in row 2 of whatever column you're adding this to, then drag it down from there.

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! IT worked!! How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Glad it worked and happy to help, if you ever need a tutor for excel I'm also available: https://www.wyzant.com/Tutors/MarkS

Comment: Noted ! I will probably contact you because i'm new to excel and I really, really need help. Also, just one more thing maybe you might be able to help .. when I created my pivot table, the groups got all messed up and they are not in order anymore.

example : (0-60) (151-210) etc... instead of 0-60, 61-90 etc..

here is a picture : https://pasteboard.co/IpNhm1c.png

Comment: In the pivot table you can click the border of any of those bucket's cells and drag them in a custom order. So from the picture click the 366 cell, grab the border on either side and as you drag it you'll see a big thick line showing it will reorder. It will remain this way until you sort it otherwise.